# Fixing malformed CSV with incorrect new line chars using sed or perl only

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl, csv

I have a comma-delimited CSV file but for some reason our system inserts a new line character at a random location in the file which causes the entire file to break. I can get the number of columns in the file.

How do I solve it with `sed` and/or `perl` in a one liner command? I know it's solvable with `awk` but this is for learning purposes. If using `perl`, I don't want to use the built-in CSV functions. Is it solvable?? I'm on this problem for several days i can't seem to find a solution :(

**Sample malformed input** (lots of randomly inserted \n)

```
policyID,statecode,county,Point longitude,Some Thing Here,point_granularity
119736,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.711777,“Residential Lot”,1
448094,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707664,“Residen
tial Lot”,3
206893,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.7
00455,“Residen
tial Lot”,1
333743,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707703,“Residential Lot”,
3
172534,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.702675,“Residential Lot”,1
785275,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707703,“Residential Lot”,3
995932,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.713882,
“Residential Lot”,1
223488,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707146,“Residential Lot”,1
4335
12,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.704613,
“Residential Lot”,1
```

**Required output**

```
policyID,statecode,county,Point longitude,Some Thing Here,point_granularity
119736,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.711777,“Residential Lot”,1
448094,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707664,“Residential Lot”,3
206893,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.700455,“Residential Lot”,1
333743,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707703,“Residential Lot”,3
172534,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.702675,“Residential Lot”,1
785275,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707703,“Residential Lot”,3
995932,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.713882,“Residential Lot”,1
223488,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707146,“Residential Lot”,1
433512,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.704613,“Residential Lot”,1
```

Comment: Find why the newlines are inserted and fix that. That would be the best resolution to the issue.

Comment: Guess: Newlines are inserted when some internal buffer is full, and written out.

Comment: For the actual question: Your lines start and end with digits, so removing all newlines *not* between digit will be a start, but this won't fix the file completely. To detect the other newlines, I guess one would need to add knowledge about how the fields look like.

Comment: How would you fix it in awk and why can't you do something similar in Perl or sed?

Comment: `on this problem for several days` please add at least one of those attempts to question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '{ while (NF < 6 || $NF == "") { brokenline=$0; getline; $0 = brokenline $0}; print }' file.csv
policyID,statecode,county,Point longitude,Some Thing Here,point_granularity
119736,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.711777,“Residential Lot”,1
448094,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707664,“Residential Lot”,3
206893,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.700455,“Residential Lot”,1
333743,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707703,“Residential Lot”,3
172534,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.702675,“Residential Lot”,1
785275,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707703,“Residential Lot”,3
995932,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.713882,“Residential Lot”,1
223488,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.707146,“Residential Lot”,1
433512,FL,CLAY COUNTY,-81.704613,“Residential Lot”,1
```

The `awk` code will append the next line of input to the current line for as long as there is less than six fields in the current line, or the last field is empty (there is one line that is broken just after the last field separator).

---

A Perl workalike:

```
perl -ne 'chomp;while (tr/,/,/ < 5 || /,$/) { $_ .= readline; chomp } print "$_\n"' file.csv
```

Comment: thank you for your response! i was trying to make it work with any type of delimiter like so: perl -ne 'chomp;while (tr/quotemeta('"$d2"')/quotemeta('"$d2"')/ < '"$columns"'-1 || /quotemeta('"$d2"')$/) { $_ .=readline; chomp } print "$_\n"' where $d2 for example is a bash variable with value || but it doesnt work :(

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I would use the `awk` solution for that as it's easier to just change the option-argument for the `-F` flag.

Comment: yeah but i need to use perl :(

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I don't quite see why.

Comment: it's ok... it just sucks that our system only has a limited amount of commands and awk is not part of it. and they don't want to install it for some reason so we have to live with sed and perl only.

Comment: what if the CSV values contain commas?

Answer (score 1):

Like say by Kusalananda, there is 6 fields on each line, so you can try this gnu sed.

```
sed -E ':A;h;s/^/,/;s/((,[^,]+){6})(.*)/\3/;/./{g;N;s/\n//;bA};g' infile
```

Comment: but unfortunately doesn't work. you didnt test it :p

Comment: Is your sed gnu sed? On Openbsd, I must change the code like that : sed -Ee ':A;h;s/^/,/;s/((,[^,]+){6})(.*)/\3/;/./{g;N;s/\n//;bA' -e '};g' infile

Comment: im using sed gnu. but thank you very much for helping me, it works now! thank you :)